# NameError: Error evaluating `PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__`: name 'PySide6' is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2, pyside6

I am trying to run the main.py which has the following code :

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PySide6 import *




########################################################################
# IMPORT GUI FILE
from ui_Dashboard_Finance import *
########################################################################

########################################################################
# IMPORT Custom widgets
from Custom_Widgets.Widgets import *
########################################################################



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

       
        # self = QMainWindow class
        # self.ui = Ui_MainWindow / user interface class
        loadJsonStyle(self, self.ui)
       

        self.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When i run the above code in the virtual environment when i have installed all the dependencies PySide2 and PySide6, its gives the following error, i have tried to import every libary which might create the problem, but still nothing improved. The OS i am using is Windows 11. The detailed error is as follows:

> File "f:\Development\desktop\OCR_Keyboard\main.py", line 62, in
>
> window = MainWindow()   File "f:\Development\desktop\OCR_Keyboard\main.py", line 42, in **init**
> self.ui.setupUi(self)   File "f:\Development\desktop\OCR_Keyboard\ui_Dashboard_Finance.py", line
> 56, in setupUi
> self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow) NameError: Error evaluating `PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__`: name 'PySide6' is not
> defined

Comment: PyQt and PySide can ***not*** be used together. Choose which one to use.

Comment: I have used all these combination by keeping the one library and commenting other but still nothing get i came back to same error.

Comment: Even i tried the pyside2 and removing the other but still the same error persist.

Comment: It's unlikely that you get the *exact same error*, you probably generated those files with the wrong tool (pyuic for PyQt and pyside-uic for PySide), or used *both* tools for different files. Check those ui files and see their import statements.

Comment: The python script i have generated from the Qt designer going in the navigation like Form--> view Python Code.. , what i have inferred from your comment that i have to generate the UI python script from pyuic or pyside-uic, is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue by updating the imports in both `main.py` and generated file (in my case: `ui_Dashboard_Finance`) to ensure consistency between the versions of PySide6 or PySide2 being used:

###### main.py

```
from PySide2 import *
```

###### ui_Dashboard_Finance

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
```

So, the final findings are: if you are using either PySide6 or PySide2 in the generated Python script, you must use the same version of PySide6 or PySide2 in `main.py`.